# NOSONAR tag to ignore an invalid issue still shows as an issue

Tags: java, sonarqube, guice, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan

I have the below method which is showing a sonar issue saying the method is not used anywhere.

```
@Provides
@ObjectMapperAnnotation
 public ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() { //NOSONAR
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());
    return mapper;

}
```

But this is a method that is called by the guice library and I do not have to call it explicitly. So in order to compress this issue I used the NOSONAR tag as shown above. But it still is showing a major issue as shown below.

```
Is //NOSONAR used to exclude false-positive or to hide real quality flaw ?
```

How can I avoid this issue being shown for using the NOSONAR tag? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

Looks like the [squid:NoSonar](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3ANoSonar) rule is activated in the Quality Profile used by this project, precisely to avoid developers silently marking stuff as *NOSONAR* i.e. sweep problems under the carpet.

Moving forward:

- let the original issue be raised in SonarQube (the one *saying the method is not used anywhere*)
- discuss it with your team to be sure it's a false-positive
- close it as *False Positive* in SonarQube (you can do that right form the UI when managing your [issues](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Issues#Issues-TechnicalReview))
- get beer